# c# Anonymous method, class property value rollbacks between function calls

Tags: c#

I have code like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
     private bool Flag;

     public void OnBar() //this is called from DoSomething();
     {
        if (Flag) //For some reason Flag=false
     }

     public void OnFoo() //this is called from some anonymous method (not mine)
     {
        Flag = true;
        DoSomething();
     }
}
```

The Callstack looks like this:
AnonymousMethod();
OnFoo();
DoSomething();
OnBar();

I have read MSDN article about outer variables with anonymous methods but they apply to local variables, what about class level variables.

Why Flag is false inside OnBar() method, and how to solve this problem.

Comment: What does `DoSomething()` do? And have you tried stepping through your code to see if `Flag` is set to true when you enter `DoSometing`?

Comment: Can you add enough code that this compiles and repros your problem?  I can't tell what is going on from the current context.

Comment: @Filip Ekberg: Flag is only used in OnBar OnFoo methods.

Comment: Is there a chance the anonymous method is on another thread? Try and setting the Flag field as volatile e.g `private volatile bool Flag;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That definitively has nothing to do with anonymous methods. It must be something that happens inside `DoSomething`.
There are basically two possibilities:

1) Flag is re-set in `DoSomething`:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    Flag = false;
    OnBar();
}
```

2) `DoSomething` creates a new instance of `SomeClass` and calls `OnBar` on that:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
    new SomeClass().OnBar();
}
```

Comment: The callstack is exectly as i wrote, no contructors, no other methods, the only thing is DoSomething is extension method but i don't think it's metter

Comment: @Alex - his point wasn't about a ctor being called from DoSomething, but that your AnonymousMethod and DoSomething are not talking to the same SomeClass object.

Comment: @Alex: Without the code of `DoSomething` all we can do is speculate. So, show us the code of this method!

Comment: From Alex's now deleted answer: "I found the problem, indeed I call OnBar from other instance of SomeClass, (it was hard to figure this out cause of IoC containers i'm using)".